# TensorFlow very slow on second run (Ubuntu)

Tags: tensorflow

I'm having a problem with TensorFlow (CPU) on Ubuntu 14.04 (VM, droplet), where running a script is fast the first time, but when running the same (or another) script directly after completion of the first run, things become very slow. 
I'm talking minutes instead of seconds. Even simple test scripts (like those provided in the tutorial) take forever, with no visible CPU load.

For comparison: first run of the test script from the tutorial gives:

```py
{real:0m0.790s, user:0m0.688s, sys:0m0.111s}
```

Second run of the same script, directly after completion of the first run gives:

```py
{real: 2m46.628s, user: 0m0.783s, sys: 0m0.104s}
```

Eventually, things seem to clear up and performance is back (only for one run though).

I narrowed the problem down to this:

```py
sess=tf.Session()
```

takes very long. Apparently resources used by a previous Session are not properly released [?]. My scripts use the Context manager, like

```py
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(...)
```

My latest hypothesis is that this has to do with system properties (virtual machine settings, hypervisor issues interacting with the context manager of TF). Using the docker container of TF makes no difference. Rebooting didn't help either. The same scripts run OK on OS X.

Comment: Is it possible you dynamically added a lot of symbols into the graph (due to some bug code) while you were running your script for the first time.

Comment: Not very likely, as it happens too with the tutorial script on https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/index.html which I assume is bug-free

Comment: How are you running the script? If you invoke it twice within the same interpreter session, as colinfang points out, there will be two copies of the nodes in the graph, which might lead to an observable slowdown. Can you try adding a `with tf.Graph().as_default():` block around each invocation of the code? This will cause the nodes from previous invocations to be freed before starting the next invocation.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm running the script(s) independently, in succession from the command line. The test script from the TensorFlow tutorial produces the same behavior.

Comment: I am now looking into https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/?nomobile=true#!topic/discuss/JN1Pi3iTTbQ where a similar issue was caused by TensorFlow waiting on /dev/random. Switching to /dev/urandom solved their problem.

Answer (score 2):

To make sure it's obvious what happened and that this question is answered:  This occurred because tensorflow was reading from /dev/random instead of /dev/urandom.  On some systems, /dev/random can exhaust its supply of randomness and block until more is available, causing the slowdown.  This has now been [fixed in github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/cd53f3c3302c9312c1840389a9988a879b8b9dd5).  The fixes are included in [release 0.6.0](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/releases/tag/0.6.0) and later.